# What are some free/public popular webservices?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, soap, silverlight-4.0

For a little personal site of mine I'm trying to come up with a list of the most popular/used webservices that my site can consume (asp.net and/or silverlight app).  I'm mostly interested in using the webservices for little dashboard-like objects (weather, news, sports scores, etc)

I've searched sites like webservicex.net and others, but was not able to narrow it down.

Yahoo and Google both have web service APIs but make it a hassle to use them during development.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it required that you can add them as a Web Service Reference or will any web service do?

Comment: I suppose any that I can use in an asp.net app will work.

Answer (score 1):

There are dozens of free stock quote services.  The free ones aren't up to date (usually lag about 15-20 minutes) but if you're just looking for some learning tools this is a good place to start.

Comment: How about ones that can get the price of a mutual fund?

Comment: I think most of them can also handle mutual funds as long as the fund posts results on NYSE or NASDAQ.  I'm not a finance guy at all, so I'm not certain - my exposure to this has been an executive portal that includes stock prices for us and some competitors.